# I want to draw a thin line on my view as shown in the images i linked

Tags: swift, line

[image]

[image]

The images explain what I want vs what I'm getting. Here is my code.

```
func drawLineFromPoint(start : CGPoint, 
    toPoint end:CGPoint, 
    ofColor lineColor: UIColor, 
    inView view:UIView) {
     let path = UIBezierPath() 
     path.moveToPoint(start) 
     path.addLineToPoint(end) 
     //design path in layer 
     let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer() 
     shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath 
     shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.CGColor 
     shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.22 
     view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer) 
    }
```

Comment: there are no images... no code and why have you wrote_like_this?

Comment: they won't let me add images unless 10 rep points somehow :(

Comment: i used this function                                                                                func drawLineFromPoint(start : CGPoint, toPoint end:CGPoint, ofColor lineColor: UIColor, inView view:UIView) {
    
    //design the path
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(start)
    path.addLineToPoint(end)
    
    //design path in layer
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.22
    
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}

Comment: @JakatX then where are the images? In case if you do not know how to attach the images to your quesetion. use [link](link to your image like http://mywebsite.com/image.png) and edit your question.

Comment: you can user bezier path or you can also use a UIView with height as 5 and width as per your requirement

Comment: can you edit your answer and add that function with formatting so that people can read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let lineView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(0, 20, self.view.width, 2)
lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.2)
```